# Use RangeSelector in Highcharts without Date

Tags: highcharts

So I built a Highcharts application which looks somewhat like this:
https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-opcho

the chart looks like this:

```
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit {
  title = "app";
  chart;
  updateFromInput = false;
  Highcharts = Highcharts;
  chartConstructor = "chart";
  chartCallback;
  data1;
  data2;
  chartOptions = {
    title: {
      text: "Global temperature change"
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: "Data input from CSV"
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        marker: {
          enabled: false
        }
      }
    },
    series: []
  }
```

A highcharts application where you can upload csv data.
If you put in csv data which looks similar to this:

```
"runs","numbers",differences
"run1","1123",21
"run2","222",7200
"run3","31112",60
"run4","412312",32
```

you will have a nice graph with x and y axis.

Now, what i am trying to do is to build in a range selector for the y axis so i can sort out really high values and have a better view on the lower values.

My problem is, i can only find range selectors that have something to do with date and time. Is there any range selector for my specific problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic range selector uses `setExtremes` method, so you can do the same on `yAxis`:

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        data: [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 999, 888, 979]
    }]
});

document.getElementById('low').addEventListener('click', function() {
    chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(0, 10);
});

document.getElementById('high').addEventListener('click', function() {
    chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(850, 1000);
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hbf2smoc/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes

Comment: is there a possible way to do this with typescript like in my example?

Comment: Hi @J.Doe, I am not a typescript expert, but it certainly is possible.